# Как избежать одинаковое значение COUNT в разных столбцах при группировке?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

Всем привет! Нужен совет как можно оптимизировать запрос и решить его без подзапроса.

Условие: Вывести ID сети, название сети, количество компаний в сети, количество юзеров в сети, где ID компании равен 7777.

Пояснение к условию:

- Есть список компаний в сетях, таблица `company`. Компании могут объединяться
  в сети, таблица `group`.
- Одна и та же компания может быть в разных
  сетях.
- Связь между компанией и сетью находится в таблице `company_group.company_id`
- Юзер в сети это не сумма всех юзеров компаний входящих в
  сеть, юзер может быть в сети один или два они входят в таблицу
  `user_group`.

Ожидаемый результат:

| g.id | Название сети | Количество компаний в сети | Количество юзеров в сети |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Название 1 | 20 | 23 |
| 6 | Название 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 56 | Название 3 | 6 | 5 |
| 98 | Название 4 | 2 | 11 |
| 235 | Название 5 | 44 | 1 |
| 679 | Название 6 | 7 | 2 |

Использую для этого запрос:

```
SELECT g.id, g.title "Название сети", count_group.c_column "Количество компаний в сети",
       COUNT(ug.user_id) "Количество юзеров в сети"
FROM (select group_id, count(company_group.company_id) as c_column
      from company_group 
      group by group_id) count_group
JOIN company_group cg ON count_group.group_id = cg.group_id
JOIN users_groups ug ON cg.group_id = ug.group_id
JOIN groups g ON cg.group_id = g.id
WHERE cg.company_id = 7777
GROUP BY cg.group_id;
```

Есть ли способ не использовать вложенные запрос для вычисления общего количества компаний или юзеров?

Если использовать запрос такого формата, то БД вернет одинаковые значения в столбцах с каунтами.

```
SELECT g.id, g.title "Название сети", COUNT(cg.group_id) "Количество компаний в сети",
           COUNT(ug.user_id) "Количество юзеров в сети"
    FROM company_group cg
    JOIN users_groups ug ON cg.group_id = ug.group_id
    JOIN groups g ON cg.group_id = g.id
    WHERE cg.company_id = 7777
    GROUP BY cg.group_id;
```

Comment: Ну я бы разворачивание подзапроса в join "оптимизацией" не назвал. по скорости наверняка проиграет, так как надо будет join'ить больше строк. А так можно использовать `count(distinct ...)` что бы подавить дубли, которые образовались в результате перемножения строк

Comment: можно отдельно посчитать первое, второе и их результаты переджойнить.